# MongoDB Schema Design, Coalesce, Merging user-specific fields with default fields

Tags: sql, mongodb, join, couchdb, nosql

Given:

A database of objects that each have a default weighting for search order (perhaps a universal popularity rating).

As each user uses those objects, the user's personal weighting for search order is stored for each item (using whatever algorithm, such as frequency of use, etc.).

In SQL this is pretty easy to do by joining the objects and user_objects tables and doing something along the lines of

```
select ... coalesce(user_objects.personal_weighting, objects.default_weighting) 
    as sort_key order_by sort_key
```

In other words, the user can search the entire DB of objects (let's say songs for example). If there's an object that the user has never interacted with before (a song they have never listened to), then the search order weighting for that object is based on a default stored for each object. If the user has interacted with an object, then that object's search order weighting is based on the specific user's weighting, over-riding the default.

Is there any efficient way to model this in MongoDB? It would be fairly easy and performant using map/reduce in CouchDB because of the indexes stored for the map/reduced views, but I haven't figured out how to do this well in MongoDB.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you cannot create index for these queries, this is going to be full table scan... Is this offline processing or an interactive query?

Comment: Online DB. Users do a full text search on title. FTS is run on objects and user_objects; results are joined by object_id & sorted by weighting (default or specific). It's simple and fast in SQL, or CouchDB, but I'm stumped on MongoDB. Most other data fits document DB structure. This DB will grow continually (each interaction with an object is recorded as a separate log, so I'm leaning away from CouchDB as I've read that it slows down considerably as views grow larger. I could do this in Mongo as map/reduce, but without an index... slow. There must be an elegant schema design I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you can make this scalable is the following:

Create a seperate collection for each user which contains only the weight for the visited objects. Add an index. Then retrieve the top weighted ObjectIds+weight from this collection. Get the ObjectIds+weights for the top weighted elements from your original collection. Merge these two lists and finally retrieve the needed elements.

All the queries are indexed so this should be fast. The pagination code for the result set is more complex (merging step) and won't work fast if your users want to check beyond.. let's say the 50th page or so (just disable it, like google does).

Comment: Thanks mate.

Assuming the weighting algorithm is effective, it's unlikely users would often dig very deep into the results pages (which would hopefully not be that long anyway after the full text search).

I was thinking along these lines, but I'm just not too sure about merging result sets in MongoDB. Is that something best done client-side? I noticed "merge" as a recent function added to MongoDB, but the reference I saw in the docs was spartan.

Comment: Yepp, you have to process the merging on the client-side. I haven't heard anything about this new "merge" feature..yet

Comment: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce  { merge : "collectionName" } - This option will merge new data into the old output collection. In other words, if the same key exists in both the result set and the old collection, the new key will overwrite the old one.
Not too sure it's relevant. I'm leaning towards just staying with Postgres. At least it's a known quantity. I flirted with the sexy nosql dbs, but at the end of the day it just doesn't quite feel right. With the indexed views of CouchDB, it's spot on, but performance for a growing db seems iffy...

Comment: ahh.. I know that option. In fact I use it :) It's not relevant. NoSQL solutions all have their sweet-spots. They only good for specific usages but for that they really outperform anything else. Flirting is good.. later you'll might see some requirements and go.. "I know Mongo is good for *that*"